# Best way to validate long list of random postal codes

Tags: javascript, postal-code

I have a long list of postal codes I have to validate.

[Link to postal codes](http://pastebin.com/ZRMgwtR7)

As you can see it's quite random there is no real order.

I tried making a switch and put in everything by hand like so:

```
switch (true) {
                    case ($(this).val().length < 5) :
                        console.log("not filled out");
                        break;
                    case (number >= 1001 && number <= 6999):
                        validated = true;
                        error = false;
                        break;
                    case (number >= 8001 && number <= 34999):
                        validated = true;
                        error = false;
                        break;
                    case (number >= 36001 && number <= 37999):
                        validated = true;
                        error = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("error");
                        error = true;
                }
```

But I quickly realised this would be a stupid long code. 
What would be a better way to validate all the ranges of postal codes?

Comment: Is there ever a scenario where you'd want error to be equal to validated? If not, why have both?

Comment: Perhaps you can store ranges of valid codes in json file (or in database) and then upon validation pull and iterate over them?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your switch for something like this

```
switch (true) {
    case ($(this).val().length < 5) :
        console.log("not filled out");
        break;
    case (number >= 1001 && number <= 6999):
    case (number >= 8001 && number <= 34999):
    case (number >= 36001 && number <= 37999):
        validated = true;
        error = false;
        break;
    default:
        console.log("error");
        error = true;
}
```

You can then add the list of rules you need